# Should an Angular 2 application be deployed on a web server or application server like Tomcat?

Tags: angular, rest

I am new to Angular. I have an application with Angular 2 and it will feed on rest services using Spring Boot running on a Tomcat server. My question is, where should the Angular application be deployed - should it be deployed on a web server like apache web server or should it be deployed in a application server like Tomcat?

I need to have it load balanced as well - so what should be my physical architecture like with the Angular app and the rest services?

Comment: You can deploy an angular application on any web or application server.

Comment: I think most people will choose the web server (like Apache or Nginx) as it's optimized for serving static content, as that's all an Angular application is, just static content. With the separation, the static content server and API server can be scaled separately as needed.

Answer (score 1):

On a web server like apache web server. Angular 2 is transpiled and works like a normal web doing in html-css-javascript.

Cheers!

Comment: so you mean it should be deployed on tomcat instead ? sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: i dont know whats your question. Angular 2 Apps should transpiled and deployed on a common web server. You are using Angular Cli?

Comment: I am new to Angular . SO really I need suggestion on what is to be done.

Comment: Then, the first thing you should do is read a basic guide of Angular Cli guy.